# Нумерация одинаковых ID в выводе MTSQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида

```
Номер заказа |Содержимое
1            |Яблоки
1            |Груши
1            |Бананы
2            |Апельсины
2            |Яблоки
3            |Мандарины
3            |бананы
3            |яблоки
3            |груши
3            |апельсины
```

Как получить таблицу вида?

```
Номер заказа |Позиция в заказе|Содержимое
    1        |1               |Яблоки
    1        |2               |Груши
    1        |3               |Бананы
    2        |1               |Апельсины
    2        |2               |Яблоки
    3        |1               |Мандарины
    3        |2               |бананы
    3        |3               |яблоки
    3        |4               |груши
    3        |5               |апельсины
```

Comment: Версия MySQL? 8+ или 5+? Надо именно *получить таблицу вида* или создать запрос с таким результатом вывода?

Comment: версия 5.6 сервер Percona. создать запрос с таким результатом вывода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица `datatable (num, val)`.

```
SELECT num, @num:=1+@num*(num=@prev) pos, val*(num=(@prev:=num)) val
FROM datatable, (SELECT @prev:='',@num:=0) x
ORDER BY num;
```

Имена таблицы и полей поменяйте самостоятельно - в вопросе их нет.

PS. Порядок нумерации значений в группе с одним номером заказа может не соответствовать исходному порядку их вывода в исходной таблице.

Comment: Получилось, единственный момент понадобился `join` :
`SELECT num, @num:=1+@num*(num=@prev) pos, val*(num=(@prev:=num)) val
FROM datatable join (SELECT @prev:='',@num:=0) x
ORDER BY num;`

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov *понадобился join* Синтаксически это одно и то же. Наверное, это заморочки препроцессора Перконы?

Answer (score 0):

По аналогии с этим [Эмуляция функции row_number() в MySQL](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/emulyaciya-funkcii-row-number-v-mysql.html)

```
create table `order_item` (`order_id` int, `item` varchar(20));
Insert into `order_item` (`order_id`, `item`) values                                                          
(1            ,"Apples"),
(1            ,"Pears"),
(1            ,"Apples"),
(1            ,"Bananas"),
(2            ,"Oranges"),
(2            ,"Apples"),
(3            ,"Mandarins"),
(3            ,"bananas"),
(3            ,"Apples"),
(3            ,"pears"),
(3            ,"oranges");
```

---

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @order_id = `order_id` THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @order_id:=`order_id` as `order_id`,
   `item`
FROM
    `order_item`,(SELECT @order_id:=1,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY order_id;
```

[An online SQL database playground for testing, debugging and sharing SQL snippets](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=1VkERidRgz)